# How can I set the list style to force prompts to be buttons?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I much prefer the look of buttons to a numbered list, but the default handling of prompt in waterfall dialog is to automatically change from buttons (default) to a numbered list after a certain length of content.

I'm currently implementing the prompt like this:

```js
return await step.prompt(FOCUS_AREA_PROMPT, {
    prompt: 'Got it. Can you confirm the focus area this is for?',
    choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(FOCUS_AREAS)
});
```

I've tried adding a style attribute within this prompt, and also tried adding to the addDialogs line `this.dialogs.add(new ChoicePrompt(FOCUS_AREA_PROMPT));` but nothing I have tried has modified the behavior of the options.

I've reviewed the [ListStyle enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/liststyle?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) in the MS docs, but any method I've tried to add these in with has not made any difference. Is there any way to force buttons regardless of content length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a choice prompt in the following manner to achieve the buttons look you are seeking. For reference, you can read more about `forChannel` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/choicefactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#forchannel-string---turncontext--string---choice----string--string--choicefactoryoptions-).

Alter to match your needs.

Hope of help!

[edit]

Updated below to represent the two ways a Choice Prompt can be assembled and how the value is output (via `imBack`). When using `toChoices`, the associated button value is returned in `activity.text` and in `stepContext.result.value` (as type `Object`). When using `forChannel`, the associated button value is returned in `activity.text` and in `stepContext.result` (as type `String`).

As discussed in the comments, the button title length has a character limit however this is channel specific. When testing in Web Chat, the limit is 20 characters. Adjusting the `FOCUS_AREAS` "AI & Machine Learning" value (21 chars) to "AI/Machine Learning" (19 chars) results in the choices displaying as buttons and not a list.

**Option 1: using `toChoices`**

```js
async choiceStep ( stepContext ) {
  const stepResult = stepContext.context.activity.text;

  const FOCUS_AREAS = [ 'Chatbots', 'RPA', 'Blockchain', 'AR/VR', 'AI/Machine Learning' ]

  if ( stepResult ) {
    return await stepContext.prompt( CHOICE_PROMPT, {
      prompt: 'Got it. Can you confirm the focus area this is for?',
      choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices( FOCUS_AREAS )
    } );
  }
}
```

```
activity:
{ type: 'message',
  id: 'A50eelAPrFIHKv9XeCRm24-o|0000021',
  timestamp: 2019-09-25T20:34:30.562Z,
  serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
  channelId: 'directline',
  from: [Object],
  conversation: [Object],
  recipient: [Object],
  textFormat: 'plain',
  locale: 'en-US',
  text: 'Chatbots',
  channelData: [Object] },
info:
{ index: 1,
  options: {},
  reason: 'endCalled',
  result:
    { value: 'Chatbots', index: 0, score: 1, synonym: 'Chatbots' },
  values: { instanceId: 'c10ed437-77eb-4502-cd24-e89d4c5e45cf' },
  onNext: [AsyncFunction: onNext] }
```

**Option 2: using `forChannel`**

```js
async choiceStep ( stepContext ) {
  const stepResult = stepContext.context.activity.text;

  if ( stepResult ) {
    const message = ChoiceFactory.forChannel(
      stepContext.context, [
        { value: 'Chatbots', action: { type: 'imBack', title: 'Chatbots', value: 'Chatbots' } },
        { value: 'RPA', action: { type: 'imBack', title: 'RPA', value: 'RPA' } },
        { value: 'Blockchain', action: { type: 'imBack', title: 'Blockchain', value: 'Blockchain' } },
        { value: 'AR/VR', action: { type: 'imBack', title: 'AR/VR', value: 'AR/VR' } },
        { value: 'AI/Machine Learning', action: { type: 'imBack', title: '', value: 'AI/Machine Learning' }, text: 'AI/Machine Learning' },
    ], `Which do you choose?`
    );
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( message );
  }
  return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
}
```

```
activity:
{ type: 'message',
  id: 'Cw5xvHTv6RCDWf3kkyS3Ir-o|0000205',
  timestamp: 2019-09-25T20:21:30.320Z,
  serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
  channelId: 'directline',
  from: [Object],
  conversation: [Object],
  recipient: [Object],
  textFormat: 'plain',
  locale: 'en-US',
  text: 'Chatbots',
  channelData: [Object] },
info:
{ index: 1,
  options: {},
  reason: 'continueCalled',
  result: 'Chatbots',
  values: { instanceId: '4becefed-88d2-773e-6184-91456609a26a' },
  onNext: [AsyncFunction: onNext] }
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that but the default behavior is that it changes to a numbered list after a certain length of item labels. In my case I'm using ChoiceFactory.toChoices(FOCUS_AREAS) to generate the choices where FOCUS_AREAS = ['Chatbots','RPA','Blockchain','AR/VR','AI & Machine Learning']. If I shorten the last option to AI/ML they render as buttons.

Comment: Also, at least with my current implementation, the way this is getting called is returning only the actual text entered (e.g. "1") instead of the associated Choice (which is returned correctly under the method listed in my original question).

Comment: It appears there is a 20 character limit to the title field. I'm testing this in Web Chat. You're mileage will vary as any character limit is going to be channel specific (i.e. Facebook may limit to 15 while Slack may allow 30). I updated the answer with additional information and two solutions.

Comment: I'll give this another go. I feel like there is an overall limit to characters as well, but I've tried so many things I can't remember if that is the way it worked out. After I do some testing I'll report back.

Comment: Ultimately I think this is the best answer I'm going to get. There appears to be no way to force buttons to override channel defaults.